# Can't deploy rails app to heroku Compilation failed: [webpack-cli] Failed to load '/tmp//config/webpack/production.js' config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, heroku-postgres

Here's the link to the git repo so you can see webpack files:
https://github.com/grantleslie/tenantportal

I can't deploy to Heroku.  I have the ruby buildpack installed on my heroku app, and the git remotes all set up but any time I try to deploy the app for the first time I get the following error:

```
Compiling...
       Compilation failed:
       [webpack-cli] Failed to load '/tmp/build_a66eb654/config/webpack/production.js' config
       [webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'plugins')
           at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_a66eb654/config/webpack/environment.js:6:13)
```

Versions:

heroku stack: heroku-20
rails -v: Rails 6.0.6.1
ruby -v: ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [x86_64-darwin22]
npm -v: 6.14.7
node -v: v12.21.0

I've tried a bunch of different webpack configurations based on stackoverflow q&a's but still get the same error.

Here is my `webpack/production.js`

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

I have tried the above with and without `.toWebackConfig()`

Here is the `webpack/environment.js` as well:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

// Add the following lines
const webpack = require("webpack")

environment.plugins.append("Provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']  // Not a typo, we're still using popper.js here
}))
// End new addition

module.exports = environment
```

Comment: @dbugger this is now added above

Comment: Please add your environment.js